# How to split a string of numbers and letters into a list of strings and a list of numbers

Tags: python

Given a string containing a sequence of letters and numbers (such as):

```
"GHG-H89KKK90KKP"
```

Do we have any way to split this string into two lists, one containing the letters and one containing the numbers?

```
["GHG-H", "KKK", "KKP"] 
[89,90]
```

Comment: Are letter and number will appear at exact same place for all strings? Can you give more examples.

Comment: Iterate a regex match for symbolic pattern, and iterate a regex match for numeric pattern

Comment: what if you have decimal numbers? should the `.` be considered part of the number or considered as a character? What if the `-` symbol comes just before a number, should it be considered a minus sign then? Or will the numbers always be positive integers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `re.findall` from the `re` (regular expressions) library to find patterns in the string. The first expression `(?i)[a-z|-]+` finds all sequences of letters (ignoring case), it also includes hyphens (`-`). The second expression `[0-9]+` finds all sequences of numbers in your string.

```py
import re

string = "GHG-H89KKK90KKP"

print(re.findall("(?i)[a-z|-]+", string))
print(re.findall("[0-9]+", string))
```

Output:

```py
['GHG-H', 'KKK', 'KKP']
['89', '90']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no straightforward way, but you an use the `re` library.
For example:

```
import re

s = "GHG-H89KKK90KKP"

out = [c for c in re.split('\d', s) if c != '']

print(out)
```

the split gives you a list of the num characters by removing the '\D' non num (or non num characters by removing the nums using '\d'), and then the we delete  the empty values. The print gives : `['GHG-H', 'KKK', 'KKP']` (for the use of '\d')